# How to put images to the right and text to the left in css

Tags: html, css

i have been teaching myself CSS using tutorials from lynda.com learning library. from what i have learned i have come to realise that using tables is not the correct way to lay out my page. until now i used a 2 column by 1 row html table to put my text in the left td and 2 images in the right td this gave me the desired effect but as stated above i have learned tables are not supposed to be used like this and i am supposed to somehow acheive this with css.

so having learnt a bit about css i tried to have a go t replicating what i had acheived with tables but this time using no tables and just css and html.

unfortunately i cannot work out how to insert code here s below is a link to a codepen i have done to show you what I am trying at present.

http://codepen.io/stuartbennett/pen/GsDgu

as you can see it aligns the images to the right but they are beside one another and below all the text. i want the 2 computers in top right corner of the page starting at the same point as the text on the left and the mcse image to stack beneathe the 2 computers on the right with all text staying on the left i am testing the non table version locally on my hard drive and not on the live site so to see the effect i get with tables that i want to recreate with css please go to http://www.admiralsystems.co.uk/index.html.

i do hope this is considered to be specific enough for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give desired effect:

```css
/* this is the clear fix, so the container doesn't collapse and has height */

.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.text {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}

.images {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <div class="text">
    Your text here
  </div>

  <div class="images">
    <img src="image1.jpg">
    <img src="image2.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

You can adjust as you see fit, but that will give you two columns, and hey, it's fluid too! Just add in a media query and it's responsive. Maybe something like:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .text, .images {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to apply the float:right to the image, which puts it on the right side of the containing div, but that containing div is still below the lettering.

Either try applying the float:right to the containing div, or take a look at the float property on w3schools which has an extremely similar example.

Comment: Other answers are correct. Style should be applied to div and also need to limit width of the items floating on left so the next div can float upward to the right.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the css for the classes `homeLeft` and `homeRight`, here is one example setting the `float` for both:

```
.homeLeft{
  float:left;  
  width:600px;
}
.homeRight{
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Apply the following changes in your css:

```
 #content {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  }
.homeLeft{
  float:left;
  width:70%;
  }
  .homeRight{
  float:right;
  width:30%;
  }
```

See source code at below link: It will show text over the image due to width issue but on wide screen or any resolution it will not be a problem

http://www.thesstech.com/youreditor?filename=dbadmin/15